# Item Response Theory model to recover the item locations

Tags: mixed-model, item-response-theory

I can't seem to find a model to solve the following problem. It seems to be closely related to IRT, but not exactly.

I have a list of users and items, I know the *preference* between users and items, in the form of:

```
[user_1, item_1],
[user_2, item_1],
[user_2, item_4],
...
```

The data is fairly sparse; each user only has preference for a very small number of items.

I'd like to **recover a mapping for both users and items on a number line, preferably with confidence intervals**. The difference from IRT seems to be twofold:

#### Difference 1

I imagine the formulation to be some linear combination of user and item (or item-cutoff) mappings, for example:

$$
logit(P_{prefer}) = x_i - \delta_j
$$

Where $x_i$ is the value of user $i$, and $\delta_j$ is the cutoff for item $j$. So if $x_i < \delta_j$, the probability is lower, and if $x_i > \delta_j$, the probability is higher.

But I really just want to minimize how "close" they are. I want to minimize $(x_i - \delta_j)^2$, for example.

#### Difference 2

The $\delta_j$ recovered from IRT are point estimates (in the 3PL model). Preferably, I'd like to recover both user and item mappings with confidence intervals.

If not IRT, I wonder if a mixed effects model could be used here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the R package [**ltm**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ltm) that fits this type of models. An example analysis of dichotomous outcomes can be found [here](http://www.drizopoulos.com/Rpgm/ltm_dichotomous.R). The model you describe seems to be the classical Rasch model covered in the example mentioned above.